# doxygen markdown code blocks in blockquote

Tags: markdown, doxygen

Is there any way to put code blocks as a blockquote with doxygen markdown? This is useful when quoting from reference books, etc. I tried the following, but it does not print the code in a fixed width font.

```
> Put the following line in your program:
>
>     printf("Hello, world.");
```

I would like that to appear like (I am using SO's markdown for illustration):

> Put the following line in your program:
>
> ```
> printf("Hello, world.");
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the doxygen manual for [markdown](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_blockquotes), The last `>` in a block quote line must be followed by a space in order for the line to be seen as a block quote. In your example above, there is no space, so the code is not seen as a block quote. If instead you specified it as (note the extra space on line 2):

```
> Put the following line in your program:
> 
>     printf("Hello, world.");
```

It should be rendered correctly.

Comment: I'll refine doxygen's implementation such that a space is not needed if the > is directly followed by a newline. Then the above example would work independent of any trailing whitespace.

Comment: @doxygen Thanks, I think that would be nice, though the current implementation is also okay.